# "net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" object is not assignable to a "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender" variable. when upgrading to spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, logback

I've upgrade from spring boot 1.5.0 to 2.0.0 and I got this error :

> ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@6f01b95f - A "net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" object is not assignable to a "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender" variable.

It seems one library needs logback-classic 1.0.13 and spring boot 2.0.0 imports logback-classic 1.2
I've tried to excluse from spring boot this library but it seems the application couldn't start without logback-classic...
[image]

Comment: can you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? that way we can see pom and see what versions do you use, easily. btw why are you targeting 2.0.0 ? there is 2.7 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/232) in Logback similar to the one you describe. It was fixed in version 1.2.5.

You can try to set the logback version property in your POM to make the Spring dependency management use that, i.e.

```xml
<properties>
    <logback.version>1.2.5</logback.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

You might also need to exclude all transitive logback dependencies
from your custom lib dependencies if there are any.

If that doesn't help, instead try to add the logback dependency explicitly to your POM to make use of Maven's nearest definition logic.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to check that the proper versions are picked up.

Comment: still not working even by forcing the library :-(

Comment: Please post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` after the modifications of your pom.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/share/yekocumure.ruby

Comment: There are no mentions of version 1.2.5 of logback in the logs.  
Try adding the `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.5` dependency to your `UserManager-NG` (`user-manager-ng-parent`) pom so that it's used in all of the subprojects and check the `dependency:tree` once again.

Comment: I got this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@3e27aa33 - A "net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" object is not assignable to a "ch.qos.logback.core.Appender" variable.
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.PropertySetter@3e27aa33

Comment: I'm testing now, I've added togerther the core with the classic and it seems working. I'll deploy and let you know.

Comment: forcing dependencies in the pom         <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
fixes the issue

Comment: I'll validate your answer when we deploy please add in it the part that we need to add core also.

Comment: Great. I don't think you have to add logback-core dep explicitly as logback-classic brings it in transitively, and from the dependency tree it looks like none of the libraries use logback-core directly. You can check it yourself - in the tree logback-core only appears as a child of logback-classic.

Comment: I checked and whenever I import only logback-classic it doesn't import the correct logback-core, not sure why